Bootstrap 5 tooltip placement top not working

      Tooltip on right


      Tooltip on top

$('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
Placement right, bottom, left works fine but the top doesn't work. If I inspect in the console it's generated but not showing. If I remove the inset it shows but the position is not correct. Can someone give me a solution for this. My bootstrap version is 5.3.3

Can you show a sample of the issue you're having either here or on stackblitz (or some other shareable code site to see the issue in action). Very likely just a problem with the css but minimal reproduction always helps.
